# ServerRaid Manager SMTP authentication

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, smtp, ibm

I need to configure IBM ServerRaid Manager (9.30.21) mail alert, but in smtp server configuration form I must insert only smtp server with no authentication.
How can I set a smtp server with athentication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a local relay that your servers can use without authentication. That relay server can then submit mail for delivery using whatever authentication methods are required.

Comment: I done this solution, but I would like to know if there is a "clean" solution or if with this ibm software il the only one.